# How can I efficiently replace the icon for documents/files of a certain type?

Tags: windows, icons

I've downloaded a set of Adobe CS4 replacement icons, and I'd like to change the Adobe applications/document icons I have to use this new set. Is there an easy and efficient way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Document/File Type icons are easily changed with **[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com)**

Start the program and click on `File Type settings` then `Icon` (as pictured below). Choose the document type you want to change the icon for. On the following page, you can choose a new icon for that document type.

[image: Default Programs Editor change an icon]

Comment: +1 This would work. This is effectively a program that does the process I had described in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

**To Change Document Icons:**

Under the Registry: Computer >> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, you'll see your file extension and a list of applications. Each extension has information that links it to an application, and each application has a DefaultIcon listed, which is how Windows Explorer determines which icon to show.

While I don't have Photoshop installed to give you a specific example, take for example the PNG extension that Quicktime has defined:

[image: Quicktime]

The default value in there shows that when Quicktime has control over the PNG extension, it will look for the icon in `C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\PictureViewer.exe` and use resource -137, which would be the resource ID for the icon.

Changing this field to point directly at your icon instead would change the default icon appropriate. You just need to find the appropriate fields for Photoshop.

**To Change Application Icons**

Simply right clicking an application shortcut and going into properties, you'll see a button to change the icon for that shortcut.

[image: Properties]

Answer (score 0):

In olden times, people used Resource Hacker to do this. If there's better alternatives today, I can't say.

http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/