# Why is incorrect associated icon showing for .MP3 files?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, vlc-media-player, file-association, gom-player

I changed the associated application for playing .MP3 files from VLC Player to GOM Player within Windows.  Double-clicking a .MP3 file causes GOM Player to launch (as expected), but the icon still shows as VLC (the traffic cone), rather than the GOM Player logo - which is confusing.  Is there any way to get the correct logo, so it shows for the associated player (GOM)?

I've tried refreshing the folder, restarting, and putting the associated application back to VLC, then GOM again to try to resolve, but it has not made any difference.

Using XP Home SP 3, with the latest release versions of GOM/VLC players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this behaviour is by design in XP.  If I use Control Panel->Folder Options->File Types to change an extension, another application can be associated, but the icon for the association stays the same (even after a restart).

For example, in [this video](http://www.ehow.com/video_4983478_change-file-type-associations-windows.html) .TXT files are set to open with WordPad instead of Notepad, but the icon stays the same.

If I use the GOM Player to set up associations, I do successfully get the icon changes as well.  Unfortunately, it does not give the option to associate itself with sound files, such as .MP3.

Comment: “By design” What does that even mean? Why would they purposely make it not work? It did not update because the icons are cached. You can fix it by clearing the cache.

Comment: *> Unfortunately, it does not give the option to associate itself with sound files, such as .MP3.* Feel free to [request](http://player.gomlab.com/eng/support/supportcenter/) they add an option.

Answer (score 1):

## To modify an existing file type

1. Open Folder Options in Control Panel.

   • Click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.

   • Click **Appearance and Themes**, and then click **Folder Options**.
2. On the **File Types** tab, click the file type you want to change, and then
   click **Advanced**.
3. If necessary, modify the file type description, and click **Change Icon** to
   change the file type icon.

This answer is from the [Windows XP Professional Product Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/win_fcab_reg_filetype_modify.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: When I go into Folder Options in Control Panel, the GOM Logo appears next to the MP3 extension, but I see the VLC logo icon when viewing MP3 files in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure why... try restarting your computer.

Comment: They said they already tried restarting.

Comment: Restarting after trying my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the icon with **[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com)** (similar questions answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/50896/how-can-i-efficiently-replace-a-programs-icon) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/145618/change-file-icons-in-windows-7))

File Type Settings -> Icon -> (search for mp3 files) -> Browse to GOM player folder, and select that program, or elsewhere in the program directory where the icon file is.

Here's an example screenshot doing that same process for another file type:
[image: use Default Programs Editor to change a file icon in Windows XP]

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your icon cache.

1. Get [TweakUI](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/tweakui.htm), install, and run it
2. Click the `Repair` branch in the tree
3. Select *Rebuild Icons* from the drop-down (it should be selected by default)
4. Click *Repair Now*
5. Reboot

Another (manual) method:

1. Open `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data`
2. Delete `IconCache.db`
3. Reboot